# How to cascade truncate with Jooq on PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, jooq, truncate, cascade

I'm writing integration tests and want to clean the (postgres) database after each test. So I assume doing a cascading truncate operation on all (actually only most of) the tables is the way to go.

I'm working on an application that uses Kotlin, Spring and Jooq which is why I imaging a `Truncator` class with a `truncateCascade` which I could get autowired into my `SpringBootTest` classes.

```
import org.jooq.DSLContext
import org.jooq.Table

@Service
class Truncator(private val dsl: DSLContext) {
    fun truncateCascade(tables: List<Table<*>>) {
        dsl.truncate ...
    }

//      single truncate work only for tables without foreign key constraints
//      so I can't simply iterate over all tables and call this method.
//    fun truncate(table: Table<*>) {
//        dsl.truncate(table).execute()
//    }
}
```

Basically I'm looking for an implementation of `truncateCascade` (assuming that's not a wrong approach).

I found documentation on Jooq's [TruncateCascadeStep](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/TruncateCascadeStep.html) and mentions of continueIdentity or restartIdentity while investigating this issue, but have not enough experience with Jooq or databases in general to piece this together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is to call `cascade()` on your `truncate()` command:

```
fun truncate(table: Table<*>) {
    dsl.truncate(table).cascade().execute()
}
```

Another option would be to simply drop your schema entirely, and re-create it from scratch. That might be more robust for testing and shouldn't take *much* more time for small to medium sized schemas.

Comment: A cascade of one looks very strange. I don't want to drop a single table, but multiple ones (therefor the `vararg` now changed to `List`, it means an array of Tables) at the same time! Otherwise the foreign key constraints will stop me. And there are tables that I don't want to drop, because there content is pretty much static, so let's not drop the schema.

Comment: @StephanS: if you run `truncate some_table cascade` it will truncate any table referencing `some_table` automatically. You don't have to list all tables in a single TRUNCATE command if you use CASCADE for every individual table

Comment: @StephanS: Well, I was assuming you were going to write that loop that you've mentioned in your comment. :) You just forgot (?) to add the `cascade()` keyword.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think that ("truncate any table referencing some_table automatically") was the missing piece of the puzzle! Thanks